# problems triggering a new image on resize in a div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a banner that when the browser is re-sized it triggers the loading of an new image, this is for a responsive website. I want one img to load at >800px and one to load at <768. I am using @media screen, and it works properly in every browser except IE. I have tried @media all, to no avail. I have also rummaged through older threads asking the same question and used some jquery options that do not work either. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
 <div><img class="center-block"></div>
```

CSS

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .center-block {
    content:url("gosalemobile.jpg");
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .center-block {
    content:url("gosale.jpg");
  }
}
```

Comment: It is IE 11, as well as Edge.

Comment: Why not have two different images. One for Desktop, One for mobile?. You can also use background-image property to display the image. And use media queries to change the background-image.

Comment: Also, content property is only supported by a small amount of browsers. As far as I know, it is only supported in webkit/chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content):

> The `content` CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

You can do the following, which should work in all major browsers:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center-block"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .center-block::before {
    content: url("gosalemobile.jpg");
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .center-block::before {
    content: url("gosale.jpg");
  }
}
```

[Fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/y3vbnxp7/1/)

Alternatively, you could use a background image and `background-size: contain`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center-block"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .center-block {
    background-image: url("gosalemobile.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .center-block {
    background-image: url("gosale.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}

.center-block {
  height: 700px; /* or some other height */
  width: 100%; /* or some other width */
}
```

(At least the height must be specified for this to work, but I find this to be more responsive)

[Fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/y3vbnxp7/)

Both solutions tested in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.. only missed IE11 because JSFiddle is messed up in IE.

Comment: So, this works great, and I really appreciate it, but it seems bootstrap is adding some sort of bottom pad to the bottom of the image now that seems to be related to  ::before IE as a space of about 20px and google has a space of about 4px any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you try forcing the margin (or padding) properties to 0 for `.center-block`?

Comment: Now I feel stupid. That worked like a charm. You are the man!